# How to swipe delete core data tableview in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a table view within a VC. It is populated from a core data object using the following code:

```
// Variables
var allFruits: NSArray
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

func loadFruits(){
    // Try to load all of the Fruits from the core data.
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Fruit", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
    do{
        self.allFruits = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        if self.allFruits.count == 0{
            print("No saved Fruits")
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
}
```

Then the table view is populated with this specific fruit data. I have got this method for deletion of the Fruits from the table

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
         // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
         managedObjectContext.deleteObject(allFruits[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)

         // Attempt to save the object
         do{
             try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
         }
             catch let error{
             print("Could not save Deletion \(error)")
         }

         // Remove the deleted item from the table view
         self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

         // Reload the fruits
         self.loadFruits()

         // Reload the table view
         tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This instead just crashes the app every time I try to delete the Fruits.

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I am suspecting that there is some issue with the fact that I am using an `NSArray` as opposed to an `NSMutableArray`.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my code by simply changing this method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {


             // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
             managedObjectContext.deleteObject(allFruits[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)

             //Attempt to save the object
             do{
             try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
             }
             catch let error{
             print("Could not save Deletion \(error)")
             }

             //Reload the fruits
             self.loadFruits()

             //Reload the table view
             tableView.reloadData()


        }
    }
```

This successfully deletes the object from the core data as well as updating the table view.

Comment: Yes, this will work because you update data source firstly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all use a Swift array rather than a Foundation array

```
var allFruits = [NSManagedObject]()
```

This avoids a lot of type casting.

To keep Core Data and the table view in sync you have to delete the object in Core Data **and** in the model. The solution to completely reload both the model and the view is very expensive and not needed at all.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .Delete {

    let objectToDelete = allFruits[indexPath.row]
    allFruits.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(objectToDelete)

    //Attempt to save the object
    do{
      try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
    catch let error{
      print("Could not save Deletion \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` includes updating the UI so reloading the table view is not needed.

If the model of the table view is `NSManagedObject` it's recommended to use `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: But then I have an issue of the code saying: Cannot assign a value of type [AnyObject] to a value of type [NSManagedObject] in the `self.allFruits = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)` part

Comment: You need to write `self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]`

Answer (score 1):

You should update data source before delete. Like this:

```
     //Reload the fruits
     self.loadFruits()

     //Remove the deleted item from the table view
     self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

And if you're sure there's no other changes,it's no need to reload data because this costs a lot.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong? I am deleting it the same way you have suggested.

Comment: @Tirat2131 I'm so so so so sorry for my mistake. Updated my answer and hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for Swift 3 Xcode 8 iOS 10**

The following code snippet adds a 'swipe to delete' to your Table Row, and also saves the changes to CoreData.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    if editingStyle == .delete {
         context.delete(tasks[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        //objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        //Save the object
        do{
            try (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        }
        catch let error{
            print("Cannot Save: Reason: \(error)")
        }

        //Reload your Table Data
        getData()

        //Reload the table view
        tableView.reloadData()

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```